# $f(x) = f(x')$ iff $x = x'$ or $\{x,x'\} = \{0,1\}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow S^1$ given by
$$f(x)=(\cos(2\pi x),\sin(2 \pi x)).$$

How can we prove that $f(x) = f(x')$ iff $x = x'$ or $\{x,x'\} = \{0,1\}$?

If $x=x'$ it is clear that $f(x)=f(x')$. And if $\{x,x'\} = \{0,1\}$ then $f(x)=f(0)=(1,0)$ or $f(x)=f(1)=(1,0)$ and $f(x')=f(0)=(1,0)$ or $f(x')=f(1)=(1,0)$. In all cases, $f(x)=f(x')$.

I don't know how to prove the other direction.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f(x)$ is a point on the unit circle. At as $x$ increases from $0$, it rotates around the circle, completing a full rotation when $x$ reaches 1. From this insight, is it possible for $f(x)$ to equal $f(x')$ if $0<x<1$ and $x\neq x'$?